# How to initialize object in Javascript when key is an id?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to Javascript, I want to initialize my object in the following way

```
{
  '101' : {
         Name: 'A',
         Add: '123'
       },
  '115' : {
          Name: 'B',
          Add: '456'
       }
}
```

and so on, I am going to execute this in a loop, the key(101,115..) is unique and value should be an object.

I tried the follow but it didn't work

```
let obj = {}

   for(i=0; i<N; i++) {

    let id = getId(i);
    let Name = getName(i);
    let Add = getAdd(i);

    obj.id = {

    Name: name,

    Add: add

    }
}
```

Comment: Use `obj[id] =`

Comment: @VLAZ Thanks a lot, it worked